# What is the state of the art of transaction costs in a pure gambling smart contract?

Tags: gas-price, gas-estimate, gambling

AFAIK, the vast majority of crypto gambling uses crypto only as a payment rail, and then implements the gambling step in a traditional (though usually provably fair) way. Using a smart contract to implement the gambling often has prohibitive transaction (gas) costs. What's the cheapest in gas costs that people have been able to write a gambling smart contract, in transaction costs per hand, per entering or exiting a game, per gambling session, per gambling partner chosen, per blocks mined while playing, etc?

Answer (score 0):

This question is unanswerable. How would one go about quantifying this metric. You would have to assemble a list of all on chain gambling contracts and then try to execute the same type of gamble on each.

Comment: I did specify many ways to quantify efficiency: gas cost per _____ (hand/session/partner/time). Since those are multiple metrics, clearly I'm interested in what the efficient frontier is for them.